# AWS phpMyAdmin not working browser when open with Putty

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, putty

I have added .ppk file is auth file
IPv4 Public Ip 
Tunnel: 8888 localhost:80
username:ec2-user

When I log in via Bash it works fine, but when trying to view in the browser it won't show
http://localhost:8888/phpmyadmin
or
http://127.0.0.1:8888/phpmyadmin

it gives 404 Page Not Found

Security Group
[image]

Comment: phpMyAdmin isn't installed at that URL on the webserver. Without details as to how it was installed and with what web server configuration this isn't resolvable by us mere SO users.

Answer (score 2):

You need to open TCP port 8888 in the ec2 Security Group. Also need to open the same port on the EC2 instance's firewall. and phpmyadmin default port is 3306 so try to open TCP port 3306 and access with ec2 instance IP with 3306 port.

steps to allow port

- Go to the "Network & Security" -> Security Group settings in the left
  hand navigation
- Find the Security Group that your instance is apart of
- Click on Inbound Rules
- Use the drop-down and add HTTP (port 8888)
- Click Apply and enjoy

Comment: I changed the TCP port 8888 and where to change the same in Instance firewall

Comment: Where do I change firewall port @skdroid

Comment: how did you install phpmyadmin and tried once with 3306 port.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html I get it from here @skdroid

Comment: and http://my.public.dns.amazonaws.com/phpMyAdmin this is also not working right ?

Comment: could you share your instance public domain name

Comment: ec2-3-14-41-160.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com @skdroid